# Is this phrase ambiguous "up to 15 mins prior to"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, ambiguity

I came across this sentence.

**"Click here to visit the event page and select 'Join now' up to 15 minutes prior to start time."**

What does that really mean? That we should join in the last 15 mins before the event (for example 12 mins before the event)?

Or that we should join more than 15 mins before the event (for example 20 mins before the event)?

To me this sounds very unclear because as far as I know "up to" means "at most". So it doesn't make sense to me somehow.

Comment: This question is better suited for ELL. That said: join up to 15 minutes prior (before) to start time (10:00 pm) would be: anytime **before** 9:45 pm. No, it is not ambiguous at all.

Comment: @Lambie OK, thanks. But doesn't "up to" mean "at most"? For example "there can be up to 3 producers" means "there can be at most 3 producers". Here if I replace "up to" with "at most" it doesn't make sense.

Comment: **up to 15 minutes before the event** can be expressed as **at most 15 minutes before the event**. So, it would make sense.

Comment: There is no logic to joining only at the last minute. You may be confusing "less than 15 means 10" with "up to 15 minutes prior means 20 is good."

Comment: @Lambie Hm, "at most 15 minutes before the event" means "15 or less than 15 minutes before the event". So from logical standpoint it doesn't quite make sense. Anyway, it is what it is.

Comment: @ Lambie:  I would read your second comment as meaning any time at or *after* 9:45pm in contrast to your first comment

Comment: Up to 15 minutes before the event: my first comment was wrong. Sorry. It means 1-15 minutes before the event. So anytime between 9:45 and 10:00.